# Automated test suite for Apache Storm 1.1.0

Tags: software-testing, apache

I have a topology that has been created using Apache storm. I have created different Bolts and spout in place to perform various activities. However, I am planning on creating an automated test suite for testing the functionalities of the topology.

Can some help me if you have done a similar thing or suggest me a tool/language that helps me to achieve it? Currently, my topology is in Java.